# MS Calendar Control 8.0 for VB 6.0

Tags: vb6, calendar-control

Does anyone know how to make the day of the week show instead of just numeric date?

I have searched the internet and found almost nothing at all on this control.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `ShowDays` property to true causes the days to be shown at the top of the calander.